# Caliburn Micro Handling Message in Code Behind

Tags: wpf, event-handling, caliburn.micro

Using Caliburn Micro MVVM, I'm trying to control a `ScrollViewer` from code behind.  I have a button click that is handled in the viewmodel.  I also need to call methods on a `ScrollViewer`, which I believe can only be done from the view.xaml.cs code behind file.
I've tried 2 things. 
1) EventHandler
2) Caliburn Micro IHandle

Neither way seems to hit the code behind file.

Here's the code for option 2

ViewModel:

```
_eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(new MyClickMessage(this));
```

Code-behind (view.xaml.cs) file:

```
public partial class MyClass: UserControl, IHandle<MyClickMessage>
{ 
public MyClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void Handle(MyClickMessage message)
{
NOT HITTING HERE
}
}
```

Any advice immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work provided that you actually subscribe in the view. Try this:

```
public partial class MyClass : UserControl, IHandle<MyClickMessage>
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IEventAggregator eventAggregator = IoC.Get<IEventAggregator>();
        eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void Handle(MyClickMessage message)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

It works just fine for me.